# Where to officially get the videos of "New Practical Chinese Reader" (1st edition)?

Tags: books

## Table of contents

- The context
- The questions
- Additional context

## The context

I'm enrolled on a course where we are using the "New Practical Chinese Reader" (1st edition), so I'm looking the original source of the videos from where I can get the videos of the book (for free or paid)

That book series consists of 6 books:

- New Practical Chinese Reader 1 (lesson 01-14)
- New Practical Chinese Reader 2 (lesson 15-26)
- New Practical Chinese Reader 3 (lesson 27-38)
- New Practical Chinese Reader 4 (lesson 39-50)
- New Practical Chinese Reader 5 (lesson 51-60)
- New Practical Chinese Reader 6 (lesson 61-70)

In Youtube, I have found the following videos

- [the videos for the 1st volume](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB1B262B05A6992FD)
- [the videos for the 2nd volume](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL76C77D2229EAF542)
- [the videos for the 3rd volume](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9E5EA79F9466CB49)
- [the videos for the 4th volume](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL14D5D3A4D4A01B8A)

I would rather download the videos from the official website instead of Youtube in order to ensure that I'm getting the same videos that the author created for the students instead of a modification of a person X.

## The questions

- From which official source can I download the videos for the volumes 1, 2, 3 or 4?
- Do the volume 5 and 6 have videos?

  - If not, please provide references or share your reasoning on how you came up to this conclusion

## Additional context

I'm aware that the 3rd edition of some volumes from the book series has already been published. In fact, some videos of those volumes are freely available ([example](http://www.blcup.com/MicroVideo/MVDetail?mvID=378)). Although I'm aware of that, I'm still interested in the volume 1 of the book series because that's the volume that the school, where I'm studying, is using and I don't think the authorities of my school will change this study plan in the near future.

Comment: Sometimes there are QR codes on the back cover of books which link to supplementary materials. I'm not sure if this is the case here.

Comment: I think you can get the textbook and companion CD from Amazon. Here is link to the 3rd ed of Vol 1. https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Chinese-Reader-Vol-English/dp/7887039754